# Winforms ObservableCollection OrderBy loose Sync

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, observablecollection

I have a grid which i load the data as following

**Method i without Sorting**

```
public partial class frmSalesOrderDetails : BaseForm.TfrmList
{
   // DECLARE OBJECTS 
   private BusinessObject.TransactionLayer.SalesOrderMaster SalesOrderMaster = new BusinessObject.TransactionLayer.SalesOrderMaster();
   private  ObservableCollection<BusinessObject.TransactionLayer.SalesOrderDetail> ocSalesOrderDetails { get; set; }
  // DATA BINDING TO GRID
  private void DataBind_grdSalesOrderDetail(int InvoiceId)
  {
    // FILL OBJECT  SalesOrderMaster , it is based on POCO so it also contains SalesOrderMaster.SalesOrderDetails
    SalesOrderMaster = (BusinessObject.TransactionLayer.SalesOrderMaster)(_Context.SalesOrderMaster.Where(t => t.InvoiceId == InvoiceId).FirstOrDefault());
    //Fill the Grid's datasource
    grdSalesOrderDetail.DataSource = SalesOrderMaster.SalesOrderDetails.ToBindingList().ToBindingList();
  }
```

**Mehod 2 with sorting**

```
public partial class frmSalesOrderDetails : BaseForm.TfrmList
{
   // DECLARE OBJECTS 
   private BusinessObject.TransactionLayer.SalesOrderMaster SalesOrderMaster = new BusinessObject.TransactionLayer.SalesOrderMaster();
   private  ObservableCollection<BusinessObject.TransactionLayer.SalesOrderDetail> ocSalesOrderDetails { get; set; }
  // DATA BINDING TO GRID
  private void DataBind_grdSalesOrderDetail(int InvoiceId)
    {
       // FILL OBJECT  SalesOrderMaster , it is based on POCO so it also contains SalesOrderMaster.SalesOrderDetails
       SalesOrderMaster = (BusinessObject.TransactionLayer.SalesOrderMaster)(_Context.SalesOrderMaster.Where(t => t.InvoiceId == InvoiceId).FirstOrDefault());
      // SORT THE DATA on a temp ocSalesOrderDetails2
      ObservableCollection<BusinessObject.TransactionLayer.SalesOrderDetail> ocSalesOrderDetails2 = new ObservableCollection<BusinessObject.TransactionLayer.SalesOrderDetail>(SalesOrderMaster.SalesOrderDetails.OrderBy(t => t.STFicheLineNo));    
      // Fill ocSalesOrderDetails with ocSalesOrderDetails2's data
      ocSalesOrderDetails = new ObservableCollection<BusinessObject.TransactionLayer.SalesOrderDetail>(ocSalesOrderDetails2);
      //Fill the Grid's datasource
      grdSalesOrderDetail.DataSource = ocSalesOrderDetails.ToBindingList();
}
```

**So the problem is as following :** When I use Method 1 and use the following code to remove (delete ) **a SalesOrderDetail :**

```
base._Context.SalesOrderDetail.Remove(((BusinessObject.TransactionLayer.SalesOrderDetail)((DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView)grdSalesOrderDetail.MainView).GetFocusedRow()));
```

All is in sync, the record is removed from Context, and grid datasource When I use Method 2  and use **delete the same way  :** There is no more sync, the record is not deleted from the grid datasource

Could anybody help please.

Answer (score 0):

If you follow this link, [ObservableCollection Constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms658737(v=vs.110).aspx) you'll see that the constructor actually creates a copy of the collection passed to it. So for your method1, when you delete a row, SalesOrderMaster from _context got changed which was instantly reflected in your object, **SalesOrderMaster** used as the DataSource.

For method2, the same is still happening, except, now in the memory, you have 2 copies of the same data. The _context value is still getting updated but that has got nothing to do with the object **ocSalesOrderDetails** which has it's own set of data used as DataSource. Actually, your grid is in sync with this variable instead of the actual result.

Easy way out is to call this method

```
DataBind_grdSalesOrderDetail(int InvoiceId)
```

after each delete operation to keep your grid both, in sync as well as sorted.

Comment: Hi P.K.  Thanks for the reply, I checked the link , so now i see that when i do a ORDERBY, it causes creation of  new ObservableCollection .While rebinding is also an option but in that case it would be no different then binding to a list. Plus i loose the current row location. Is there any alternative to ObservableCollection ?

Comment: I am afraid no matter what collection you use, to sort your collection, you have to call the `ORDERBY()` which will create a new copy of data. This is important because any changes to the context gets directly mapped to the database. So we don't wanna change the database values for sorting. Our custom sorting req  (asc or desc) should be done at the front end. I would recommend to just update your grid, DataSource & DataBind after each operation (add/update/delete).

Comment: So you say that in order to NOT loose the row location , the datasource can not come from a statement that contains ORDERBY, and the otherwise i need to rebind the data each time ?